Inscribed sphere and circumscribed sphere of a cone

Suppose the base radius and the height of a right circular cone are
$8$ cm and $15$ cm respectively. Find the ratio of the radius of the
inscribed sphere to that of the circumscribed sphere of the cone.


I am getting two different answers by using two different methods, while the suggested answer is different from what I get. My methods rely on the cross section of the cone and the spheres and the fact that the points $A$ and $D$ lie on the circumscribed sphere.
Suggested answer: The ratio is $\frac{144}{289}$.
My first attempt:
Note that $\Delta ABE$ is similar to $\Delta ADC$. Hence, $$\frac{BE}{AB} = \frac{CD}{AD} = \frac{8}{17}$$ which implies that the required ratio is $\frac{8}{17}$ as $AB$ is a radius of the circumscribed sphere and $BE$ is a radius of the inscribed sphere.
My second attempt:
Let $a$ and $b$ be the radii of the inscribed sphere and the circumscribed sphere. By considering $\Delta BCD$, we have $a^2 + 8^2 = b^2$. By considering $AB + BC = AC$, we have $b + a = 15$. On solving, we have $a = \frac{161}{30}$ and $b = \frac{289}{30}$. It follows that the required ratio is $\frac{161}{289}$.
I am not sure why my methods are wrong. Any help is appreciated.

$B$ is the incentre but not the circumcentre of triangular crosssection of the cone. So $AB$ isn’t the radius of the circumsphere.

@Pranay - So the circumscribed sphere touches the vertex of the cone $A$, but $B$ is not the centre of the circumscribed sphere. Am I right?

Yes, that’s right. It is on the line $AC$ because that triangle is isosceles, but it’s not $B$.
